# Secure a website

Tags: security

I've to make an introduction to what kind of attack  they should prevent on their custom website.

I already made some example about XSS, CSRF, SQL Injection, is there something else I should include?

This presentation will be for programmer, so I only need to show some code issue and how to resolve them in code, so no bruteforce, no DoS, man-in-the-middle. And it should be something I can demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think You Need

File Upload Examples

code Execution

Session Fixination

Session Hijack

Cookie Insecure

Remote - Blind - bypass      Sql Injection

Remote - local  Dictionary Traversal

Remote - local  File Include & File Disclure

And More :)

Comment: What is the File upload risk?

Comment: @J4N: google for "zip bomb". Also if you allow to upload images, they can contain exploits which can either attack your server or the browser when users download them (avatar images). And what happens if a user uploads a 50GB file?

Answer (score 3):

See detailed [Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aAttack) and [Vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aVulnerability)

Comment: I already saw that, but I need only problem which can be issued of a bad code

Comment: :) that was not clear earlier..nps

Answer (score 1):

Easy to demonstrate, besides the ones you mention:

- Path traversal ("myplace.com/Files/Getfile=../../../file.config")
- Authorization bypass ("myplace.com/userId=34234")
- Arbitrary redirection ("myplace.com/login.aspx?returnUrl=somehwereelse.com/page.aspx")

You should consider brute force, applications should be ready to log and block repetitive login attempts for example.

Also the man in the middle attacks, are easy to demonstrate using a proxy :) Lot of developers fails in something as simple as put the login form in HTTPS as well, or explain what a "Session fixation" attack is about.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

php upload risk

hacker can upload php shells in many types like

`.php` like this example http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/16058/

`.php.jpg`  like this example http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/17303/

and there is other ways by editing the http headers like

you can upload php file but edit the header and make the file in image type

example

```
$allowed = array("image/jpg","image/png","image/gif");
$file    = $_FILES['file']['type'] ; 

if(in_array($allowed , $file)  { upload this file}
else{ not allowed msg }
```

here when tried to upload php file header will sent like Content-type: `application/octstream`

you can edit it using example tamper data in fire fox addons

and just edit contents type to `Content-type: image/gif`

like http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/16181/

or you can use .htacces file if php is not alloweed

```
$deny = ".php|.pl|.html|.asp";

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name']

$ext = strrchr($filenae , ".");

if(preg_match("/($ext)/", $deny)){
  deny msg there is php word or others
}
```

you can here upload `.htaccess` file  contain this

```
<FilesMatch ".gif">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

here you told appache server to work with this files type "gif" as  php file

like this http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/17644/

and there is many ways with this risks :)

regards

Answer (score 0):

- Brute force attacks
- Spamming (forums etc)

Answer (score 0):

Session Management

Security Configuration

Cryptographic storage

Comment: Those are topics, not attacks, and for now I'm only interessted on problem which are issued of a bad code